# XCode not using decimal number, only using whole digit

Tags: ios, decimal, calculator

I am trying to multiply three TextField's values which are in numbers. These values can contains decimal places. In multiplication Objective-C does not consider decimal places. For example, if the number was 3.45, it would only multiply by 3 and not with the decimals as well. Might be a basic question but i am stuck and really need help!

Here's the code i'm using so far:

```
- (IBAction)CalculateSimple:(id)sender {
int sum = [[principal text] intValue] * [[rate text] intValue] * [[loan text] intValue];;
total.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", sum]; }
```

Comment: Your data type is int and you are converting it to int

Comment: If you don't know the difference between an integer and a float, you should not be programming in Objective-C.  It is not a beginner's language.

Comment: @HotLicks should not be telling me what i can and can't do, thanks.

Comment: You came here for advice and you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `double` instead of `int`:

```
double sum = [[principal text] doubleValue] *
             [[rate text] doubleValue] *
             [[loan text] doubleValue];
total.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%f", sum];
```

Comment: thankyou so much! how would i go about dividing this sum by 100? I really need/want to learn :)

Comment: Add `sum /= 100.0;` between those two statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are using intValue (which returns integer type, thus your calculations are done on integers). You need to use floatValue or doubleValue (depending on your needs).
Also - check int/float/double types, if you don't know them yet.

Answer (score 1):

You transform each of your operands to an `intValue`. Furthermore your result is also declared as an `int` variable.

Variables of type `int` can only store whole numbers.
If you want to work with floating point numbers use an appropriate data type like `float` or `double` depending on your desired precision and the size of the value.

Take the [documentation on values in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html) as a reference.
When you are printing your result you also have to match the placeholder to the data type. 
See the [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

So with that in mind your method would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)CalculateSimple:(id)sender {
   float sum = [[principal text] floatValue] * [[rate text] floatValue] * [[loan text] floatValue];
   total.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%f", sum];
```

}